# Is there any "Pos" function to find bytes?

Tags: delphi, arrays

```
var
  FileBuff: TBytes;
  Pattern: TBytes;
begin
  FileBuff := filetobytes(filename);
  Result := CompareMem(@Pattern[0], @FileBuff[0], Length(Pattern));
end;
```

Is there any function such as

```
Result := Pos(@Pattern[0], @FileBuff[0]);
```

Comment: Pos is binary safe, feed it with arrays of AnsiChar and voila, works

Comment: You might also be interested in a StringReplace function for bytes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106139/binary-version-of-stringreplace

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this does it:

```
function BytePos(const Pattern: TBytes; const Buffer: PByte; const BufLen: cardinal): PByte;
var
  PatternLength: cardinal;
  i: cardinal;
  j: cardinal;
  OK: boolean;
begin
  result := nil;
  PatternLength := length(Pattern);
  if PatternLength > BufLen then Exit;
  if PatternLength = 0 then Exit(Buffer);
  for i := 0 to BufLen - PatternLength do
    if PByte(Buffer + i)^ = Pattern[0] then
    begin
      OK := true;
      for j := 1 to PatternLength - 1 do
        if PByte(Buffer + i + j)^ <> Pattern[j] then
        begin
          OK := false;
          break
        end;
      if OK then
        Exit(Buffer + i);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: I would use a formal parameter instead of pbyte. Means the same, but compatible with more types.

Comment: @Andreas, I think it does not do it:  If the pattern is not found, your routine will return a pointer to the first byte... how would you difference if the pattern is found at the first byte?  Better return nil in case pattern is not found.

If the first and second byte of the pattern match, your routine returns the address of that second byte and exits (without further comparing the rest of the pattern)

Comment: @Andreas More than none at all is too much!

Comment: I wonder if there is a "fastcode" version of the function. Nevermind, It already works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Write your own. No optimization can be done when looking for just one byte, so any implementation you'll find would basically do the same thing.

Written in browser:

```
function BytePos(Pattern:Byte; Buffer:PByte; BufferSize:Integer): Integer;
var i:Integer;
begin
  for i:=0 to BufferSize-1 do
    if Buffer[i] = Pattern then
    begin
      Result := i;
      Exit;
    end;
  Result := -1;
end;
```

Comment: I think @user wants capability of multi-byte patterns

Comment: Yes you only find one byte pattern, and requirement is multi-byte.