# Comparing arrays in Delphi

Tags: arrays, delphi, indexing, compare

I have 3 arrays, for example:

```
const
  A: Array[0..9] of Byte = ($00, $01, $AA, $A1, $BB, $B1, $B2, $B3, $B4, $FF);
  B: Array[0..2] of Byte = ($A1, $BB, $B1);
  C: Array[0..2] of Byte = ($00, $BB, $FF);
```

Is there a way to compare and get the index of the right one, instead of checking each byte 1 by 1? For example:

```
function GetArrayIndex(Source, Value: Array of Byte): Integer;
begin
..
end;

GetArrayIndex(A, B); // results 3
GetArrayIndex(A, C); // results -1
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Here is the answer, [Is there any “Pos” function to find bytes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4959566/576719).

Comment: Great and fast reply. (i spent about 1h and half to find nothing while u did it in ..5'?). Thank you! I have to study some more about pointers and such in order to make use of those functions.

Comment: I will post a reworked version of Andreas answer for you to study.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
function ByteArrayPos(const SearchArr : array of byte; const CompArr : array of byte) : integer;
//  result=Position or -1 if not found
var
  Comp,Search : AnsiString;
begin
  SetString(Comp, PAnsiChar(@CompArr[0]), Length(CompArr));
  SetString(Search, PAnsiChar(@SearchArr[0]), Length(SearchArr));
  Result := Pos(Search,Comp) - 1;
end;
```

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: I wonder if your answer is yes or no. I mean, does `Pos` perform a *check of each byte 1 by 1*?

Comment: Yes and No, of course somwhere has to be done a check byte by byte, but there is no need to be reimplemented.

Comment: @bummi - Ok, it makes sense.

Comment: Because this function treats the data as strings internally I was not sure if that would work when you have zeroes in the data, but I've tried it and it works.

Comment: @Wouter It works because it operates on strings rather then PAnsiChar.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a reworked version of Andreas answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4959721/576719).

```
function BytePos(const Pattern: array of byte; const Buffer : array of byte): Integer;
var
  PatternLength,BufLength: cardinal;
  i,j: cardinal;
  OK: boolean;
begin
  Result := -1;
  PatternLength := Length(Pattern);
  BufLength := Length(Buffer);
  if (PatternLength > BufLength) then
    Exit;
  if (PatternLength = 0) then
    Exit;
  for i := 0 to BufLength - PatternLength do
    if Buffer[i] = Pattern[0] then
    begin
      OK := true;
      for j := 1 to PatternLength - 1 do
        if Buffer[i + j] <> Pattern[j] then
        begin
          OK := false;
          Break;
        end;
      if OK then
        Exit(i);
    end;
end;

begin
  WriteLn(BytePos(B,A)); // 3
  WriteLn(BytePos(C,A)); // -1
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Bummis answer is to prefer, though. Much better.

---

Just a remark as noted in the comments.

For small datasets `BytePos` outperforms `ByteArrayPos`, while for large datasets (10000 items) the performance is reversed.

This is for the 32-bit mode, where the assembler optimised `Pos()` system function works at its best for large datasets.

In 64-bit mode though, there is no assembler optimised Pos() function.
In my benchmark test, `BytePos` is 4-6 times faster than `ByteArrayPos`, for all types of dataset sizes.

---

**Update**

The benchmark test was made with XE3.

> During the test I discovered a flawed `purepascal` loop in the System.pas function `Pos()`.

An improvement request has been added, [QC111103](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=111103), where the proposed function is about 3 times faster.

I also optimised the above `BytePos` a bit and present it here below as `ByteposEx()`.

```
function BytePosEx(const Pattern,Buffer : array of byte; offset : Integer = 0): Integer;
var
  LoopMax    : Integer;
  OK         : Boolean;
  patternP   : PByte;
  patStart   : Byte;
  i,j        : NativeUInt;
begin
  LoopMax := High(Buffer) - High(Pattern);
  if (offset <= LoopMax) and
     (High(Pattern) >= 0) and
     (offset >= 0) then
  begin
    patternP := @Pattern[0];
    patStart := patternP^;
    for i := NativeUInt(@Buffer[offset]) to NativeUInt(@Buffer[LoopMax]) do
    begin
      if (PByte(i)^ = patStart) then
      begin
        OK := true;
        for j := 1 to High(Pattern) do
          if (PByte(i+j)^ <> patternP[j]) then
          begin
            OK := false;
            Break;
          end;
        if OK then
          Exit(i-NativeUInt(@Buffer[0]));
      end;
    end;
  end;
  Result := -1;
end;
```

Comment: Yeah, i can understand your reworked function way easier than the original. Thank you so much for your effort.

Comment: It's not as easy to read as Bummi's implementation, but in theory this could be much faster because it doesn't copy the data. Therefore +1 for this one too. It could make a difference if it's used often or on large datasets. I didn't actually measure the difference though.

Comment: @WoutervanNifterick, I did a benchmark on one small dataset (the one above) and one large dataset (10000 elements). For a hit at the end, `BytePos` is a little bit more than 3 times faster in the small dataset, while for the large dataset the result is the opposite. Conclusion: The allocation of the two strings in `ByteArrayPos` will give a performance penalty for small datasets, while the optimised `Pos` system function excels for large datasets.

Comment: @LURD, did you have optimization off or on?

Comment: @AndreasHausladen, optimization on, running in release mode.

Comment: Sorry, deleted last remark. This is what I ment to say: Oh, I should mention that the bench mark was in 32 bit mode. In 64 bit mode, there is no assembler optimised `Pos()` function. And performance is much worse than `BytePos`. A factor of 4-6 for both small and large datasets.

Comment: @LURD u miss one more optimization - and the reason PByte would be better than array access in loops :-)
Unless `Pattern[0] = Pattern[1]` you should skip the rest of the buffer searched in inner loop. I don't recall who were persons 1st coined this algorithm, yet you should have a variable `distance` as offset to next occurrence of 1st byte in the pattern, so that you'd just skip the reasonless search of Pattern[0] for next J characters :-)

Comment: @Arioch'The, keeping track of alternative pattern start inside the inner loop would perhaps be effective. Did you try? I studied how the purepascal implementation of Pos was made. Yes, it was short in terms of instructions, but much less effective than BytePos. I have one optimised version of BytePos that speed things up a bit for large datasets in 32 bit mode, using PByte.

Comment: @LURD no, just speculating. Actually i do not need fast substring search :-)  But i once thought about it and finally googled two names and compared their algo with my ideas. And actually to me it would not be hard to code this in x86 assembler, if i need, so i just don't care about DCC codegen efficiency to measure.  BTW, does `SetString` copy content like `UniqueString` does ? other than that i cannot see why your code can be faster than bummi's one

Comment: @LURD if that "keeping track" means jumping to the next unscanned char, I+J, then that is less efective. Consider pattern "ABCDAB" in buffer like "ABDEFABCDAB". Current code would scan "B" and "D" letters twice and all the rest once. With `I+J` modification all letters would be scanned once. With `distance` var letters "E" and "F" would be skipped and never considered. Okay, in this example it would probably make no difference - the buffer would anyway be completely pulled into CPU cache, but on some more sparse pattern it might make a difference.

Comment: @Arioch, [SetString](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SetString) makes a copy. I can't see how to skip E and F, since they can be a beginning of a new pattern. And for hand-coding assembler, have not done that for the last 25 years :-)

Comment: @LURD u're probably right about E and F, my memory probably failed me.   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer–Moore_string_search_algorithm

Comment: @Arioch, you were maybe thinking of the [Boyer-Moore algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm), which can set up jump tables to skip parts of the search string.